# How to Get PID of an OutPorc Com EXE

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I need to get the `PID` of an `OutProc` com exe.I compare the szExeFile given by `Process32First()` with my Exe name. If both the name are same, I use the `th32ProcessID` given by `Process32First()`.
Is there any better way of getting the `PID` of `outproc` com exe?

Comment: you have not stated how much control you have of the server, if it is your own then extending it with this functionality would seem to be easiest like sharptooth says in his comment ;-)

Comment: @SimonMourier: Nope, a process handle is not the same as process id.

Comment: @sharptooth - of course, but it's basically the same question with the same answer. I can be patronizing too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier: Actually the answer is not the same. A process handle makes no sense when transferred between processes but a process id does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way - introduce a method to one of the interfaces (or craft a new interface for that) that will just obtain the current process id and return it to the caller.